# Programmatically removing User Rights Assignment (SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege)

Tags: windows, powershell, security, gpo

I am trying to modify User Rights Assignment on Windows 10, using the command-line; specifically, I want to remove "NT VIRTUAL MACHINE\Virtual Machines" from the "Create symbolic links" right.

I have tried a few different methods so far, but nothing has worked short of manually configuring via the Local Group Policy Editor GUI...
What I've tried:

- exporting User Rights Assignment via secedit, modifying them, then re-importing -- I've verified that the modifications are made correctly, and this *appears* to succeed, but the account is not actually removed from "Create symbolic links"
- LGPO to export Security Settings, modifying them, then re-importing
- this guy's excellent-looking Microsoft-signed script: https://blakedrumm.com/blog/set-and-check-user-rights-assignment/
- ntrights.exe (a tool from Windows Server 2003 -- it does not appear to be aware of/support SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege)

In all cases (except for ntrights.exe), I seem to be getting syntax right, but it is not being removed. It doesn't seem to be an especially privileged setting, because I'm able to do it as an Administrator through the Local Group Policy Editor GUI.

Anyone have any ideas? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!